# How can I use CaseMgmtContext in Job Sweeps?

Tags: java, filenet-p8, ibm-case-manager, filenet-cpe

I am writing a custom job sweep action in java

I would like to use CaseMgmtContext so I don't have to read username and properties file

Unfortunately I can't seem to use CaseMgmtContext without a VWSession and there is no VWSession in job sweep.

Q: How can I get usercontext ( for example : ICM CaseMgmtContext ) in a Job Sweep?

Are there any applicable API's in JACE, Is there any way to use CaseMgmtContext without a VWSession?

Thank you in advance.